# Error Occured when createing project with phonegap in command prompt

Tags: android, cordova

**This is the command prompt screen :-**

C:\development\cordova-2.3.0\bin>create D:\Parvindra\Work For android with sdk\a
dt-bundle-windows-x86-20130729\eclipse\android_projects com.android.parvindra pa
rvindra
Microsoft (R) Windows Script Host Version 5.8
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Input Error: There is no script engine for file extension ".js".

***I'm new to phonegap 
Please solve the Input Error : There is no script engine for file extension ".js". If any one knowing this with phonegap*.**

Answer (score 0):

Download from below link , i

```
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8247
```

But that file is not supplied. There are updated instructions here (see section 2.1).

Here is the issue at apache: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-1531

See also this question for more details: Not Able To Install Apache Cordova for Windows Phone7